# UISplitView Controller Modification and Human Interface Guidelines

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, appstore-approval, human-interface

I'm trying to customize the location of my split vew controller, wanting to shift the UISplitView down by 200 pixels, in order to place a banner.  I managed to do this by creating a CGFrame in my app delegate, and drawing the The Splitview in this frame.

Can someone who's familiar with the App store approval let me know if this will be an issue, and if there are any workarounds that will let me reposition the splitview?   Are there any other solutions other than the one found [here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/).

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

Thanks

Comment: I'll let you know.  I'm currently working on an approach with a custom UIViewController (so iAd doesn't moan about being in a view with no view controller) and a view added to the bottom in landscape mode so I can display iAds.  I have concerns about it being accepted, but I won't know until I try.

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing ugly things like that for quite some time now, and Apple seems not to complain about them....

Another implementation of the Split View you can use, that maybe makes it easier for you to shitf the split view, is this: http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad